# Asymptotic bound of $\sum_{i=0}^{\log(n)} 2^{i} \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2^{i}}} (k+2)^{2} + \theta(n)$

Tags: asymptotics

What is the asymptotic bound for $\sum_{i=0}^{\log(n)} 2^{i} \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2^{i}}} (k+2)^{2} + \theta(n)$?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). If I am not mistaken, the following does the job.

```
Normal[Series[Sum[2^i*(k + 2)^2, {i, 0, Log[n]}, {k, 0, n/2^i}], {n, Infinity,1}]] //FullSimplify
```

> $$\frac{1}{9} n^3 \left(4-2^{-2 \log (n)}\right)+n^2 \left(5-5\ 2^{-\log (n)-1}\right)+\frac{37 n}{6}+\frac{37}{6} n \log (n)+2^{\log (n)+3}-4 $$

One sees the main term of the asymptotics is $\frac 4 9 n^3$.

Comment: According to the documentation `O[x]^n` represents a term of order $x^n$ not necessarily giving a bound.

Comment: @Sorry, don't understand it though I'm PhD in math for ages. Can you kindly elaborate your comment ?

Comment: Yes. Consider the Bessel function `BesselJ[0,x]`. Its leading term in series expansion at infinity reads `Sqrt[2/π] Cos[π/4-x]/Sqrt[x]`. It represents a good approximation, but does not give a bound such as $|J_0(x)|<1/\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: see here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+besselj%280%2Cx%29+%2C+1%2Fsqrt%28x%29%2C+-1%2Fsqrt%28x%29++from+1+to+300

Comment: @yarchik: Are you serious? The question is about an asymptotic bound and this asymptotic bound as $n$ approaches infinity can be taken $\frac {4+\epsilon} 9 n^3$ with an arbitrary $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: I do not question your result. I am stating that in a general setup `Series` is not a tool to generate the asymptotic bounds. They can be obtained with further analysis based on it. The word bound often comes with a specification "from above" or "from below". This notion is not present in the big-O notation, nor is it a part of `Series` command.

Comment: To finish this thread, up to the common definitions, the upper asymptotic bound under the consideration can be taken $\frac {4+\epsilon} 9n^3$ and the lower one can be taken $\frac {4-\epsilon} 9n^3$ with an arbitrary $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: Note that we don't even need `Series` for this summation. `In[14]:= summation = Sum[2^i*(k + 2)^2, {i, 0, Log[n]}, {k, 0, n/2^i}];

In[15]:= terms = 
  List @@ Expand[
    summation /. a_^(b_. + c_. Log[n]) :> a^b*n^(c Log[a])];

In[16]:= Last@Sort[terms, AsymptoticLess[##, n -> ∞] &]

Out[16]= (4 n^3)/9`